# Bundles with nonzero Stiefel class over $\mathbb{CP}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, principal-bundles

Could you please show me an example of a principal $SO(3)$-bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^2$ such that the restriction of this bundle on a projective line is non-trivial.

Edit: One can try to construct the map $f\colon \mathbb{CP}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{CP}^1$ such that $f_{*}\colon H_2(\mathbb{CP}^2) \mapsto H_2(\mathbb{CP}^1)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: One can construct the map $f\colon \mathbb{CP}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{CP}^1$ such that $f_{*}\colon H_2(\mathbb{CP}^2) \mapsto H_2(\mathbb{CP}^1)$ is isomorphic.

Comment: It seems you find my question silly. It should be very easy for you to answer.

Comment: No, it's not silly at all. I am simply encouraging you to make the most of this community. We prefer to help people learn, rather than just provide them with answers, so we would like to understand how you see the problem. Let us help you answer it yourself. I am not sure I can answer this. Even if I could, I'm afraid I don't have time; I just have coffee. Good luck with it :)

Comment: Are you talking about a bundle with structure group $SO(3)$ or fiber $SO(3)$? If it's the former, then you're just looking for an orientable $3$-bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^2$ whose restriction to a projective line is nonorientable. If it's the latter, then try considering the action of $SO(3)$ on $\mathbb{CP}^2$.

Comment: I want the bundle to be oriented. Maybe I should put the word "principal".

Comment: Your note about an action of $SO(3)$ on $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is not clear for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb C)$ you have the tautological complex line bundle $\xi$ .
The rank-3 real vector bundle  $E=\xi\oplus \mathbb 1_\mathbb R$  can be reduced to an $SO_3(\mathbb R)$-vector bundle since it is orientable.
It has non trivial restriction to any complex line $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)\subset  \mathbb P^2(\mathbb C)$ by the following   calculation involving Chern and Stiefel-Whitney classes: $$w_2(E)=w_2(\xi)=c_1(\xi) \operatorname {mod} 2=\overline {-1}\ne \overline {0}\in H^2(\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C),\mathbb Z/2)=\mathbb Z/2$$

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you one more question? Let us consider the bundle $(\xi \otimes \xi)\oplus 1_{mathbb{R}}$; there is the obstruction in $H^{4}(\mathbb{CP}^2)$ to construct a section for the corresponding $SO(3)$-bundle. This obstruction is an integer number. How one can find it?

Comment: Dear Gleb, maybe you should ask a new question on the site? I will certainly consider it , and so would some other users.

Comment: Ok, I shall post the another question.